# find query with multiple elementmatch in a collection

Tags: mongodb

I have some problems trying to find the appropriate query for looking the data in my table, I had already tried with elementMatch, read a lot in another questions. Trying to $redact but I can only get 1 of the 2 documents. What I am doing wrong? Why I am getting only one? 
I have this document

```
   {
"_id" : "dff26f9c-350b-4bd5-bc62-62c19f21100c",
"sensorId" : "123456",
"sensorModel" : "LOOP",
  "attachments" : [ 
    {
        "type" : "StructAttachment",
        "data" : "STRUCT DATA"
    }, 
    {
        "type" : "BlobAttachment",
        "data" : { "$binary" : "QkxPQl9EQVRB", "$type" : "00" }
    }, 
    {
        "type" : "otherData",
        "data" : { "$binary" : "QkxPQl9EQVRB", "$type" : "00" }
    }
]
```

}

And the result I am looking for is

```
   {
"_id" : "dff26f9c-350b-4bd5-bc62-62c19f21100c",
"sensorId" : "123456",
"sensorModel" : "LOOP",
  "attachments" : [ 
    {
        "type" : "StructAttachment",
        "data" : "STRUCT DATA"
    }, 
    {
        "type" : "BlobAttachment",
        "data" : { "$binary" : "QkxPQl9EQVRB", "$type" : "00" }
    }
]
```

}

I want to filter through _id and for attachment.type ("structAttachment" or "blobAttachment")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/#exp._S_filter) with [$setIsSubset](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIsSubset/) as below :

```
db.collectionName.aggregate({
  "$project": {
    "sensorId": 1,
    "sensorModel": 1,
    "attachments": {
      "$filter": {
    "input": "$attachments",
    "as": "el",
    "cond": {
      "$setIsSubset": [
        ["$$el.type"],
        ["StructAttachment", "BlobAttachment"]
      ]
    }
      }
    }
  }
}).pretty()
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply, you miss the id but I was able to add with 
db.getCollection('measurement').aggregate(
  {
 $match : {"_id" : "dff26f9c-350b-4bd5-bc62-62c19f21100c"}
    },
{
  "$project": {
     
    "sensorId": 1,
    "sensorModel": 1,
    "attachments": {
      "$filter": {
    "input": "$attachments",
    "as": "attachment",
    "cond": {
      "$setIsSubset": [
        ["$$attachment.type"],
        ["StructAttachment", "BlobAttachment"]
      ]
    }
      }
    }
  }
})